# Is google charts deprecated?

Tags: php, graph, charts

I am slightly confused as to whether Google charts is deprecated or not? I am wanting to draw graphs and charts onto my webpage and obviously would not want to use a deprecated charting component.

Comment: You just need to use their latest charts which aren't just static images, they have annotative abilities, mouse-over effects, etc...  see here: https://developers.google.com/chart/

Answer (score 7):

AFAIK, it's only the image API that's deprecated.

https://developers.google.com/chart/image/

> Important: The Image Charts portion of Google Chart Tools has been
>   officially deprecated as of April 20, 2012. It will continue to work
>   as per our deprecation policy.

[It looks like there is still a year left until they completely get rid of the API though](https://developers.google.com/chart/terms)